# how to run the python script from batch command?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, batch-file, mount

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set Error=0
#set TEST_LANG=ENG GED

subst /D H: 2>nul
Net use H: /DELETE /YES 2>nul
Net use H: \\10.165.128.44\_ance_7" 2>nul

if not exist H:\ (
    echo [ERROR] Problem mounting S: drive! Cannot start the test!
    goto END
)
VERIFY > nul
H:

    echo.
    echo Running FRAMEWORK_Errors_with_IDs.py 
    call python FRAMEWORK_Errors_with_IDs.py -l 
    if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" echo errorlevel is %errorlevel%
    if not "%errorlevel%"=="0" set Error=1


:END
EXIT /B %Error%
```

The above is my .bat code. which mounts the server to the Drive H and later calls my python script.
The below is my python script FRAMEWORK_Errors_with_IDs.py : which searches for a .log which starts with VCALogParser_output name. Later it checks for scenario is failed, if it is then writes that test case id to the output file.
it is working fine without batch command on my pc. If I mount the server to PC and run the batch command then it is executing and printing the empty output.txt. can someone help me ?

Comment: I solved it. thanks.

Comment: please share the solution in the answer section and accept answer for the same.